# Return structure pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Could you please help me in correcting my code:

This is a function that returns a pointer to struct item:

```
struct item* findItem(const char* key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(items[i].key, key)) { return &items[i]; }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

From main function, I want to retrieve my struct value as following:

```
struct item search_items = findItem(&key) ; // I have problem with this line 
char* itemValue;
if (search_items != NULL)
{
    itemValue = search_items->value;
}
```

How can I retrieve the structure and save it to be used in the `main` function?

Comment: What problem you are facing? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Please paste your complete code.

Comment: In addition to the answer(s) below: consider what is going to happen to `itemValue` if `findItem` returns NULL.

Comment: i can not post the code because it is part of socket programming assignment and if someone copied the same code i will get zero mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are returning pointer from function, then you have to read it as pointer.
Notice `struct item* search_items` part on my code and on your (I added pointer `*`)

```
struct item* search_items = findItem(&key) ; // i have problem with this line 
char* itemValue;
if ( search_items != NULL)
{
    itemValue = search_items->value;
}
```

Comment: yes i did the same and it worked + also i removed &key and pass key only .. it now executed but i always get an empty value from search_items

Comment: Well, does your string exist? The code has been properly corrected. Now it is up to you to either show more code, what `key` is or similar.

Comment: how can i access to the memory to check weather the struct is stored correctly or not ?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do so I don't have an answer.

Comment: using gdb debugger solved my issue .. apperently i was not saving the struct using memcpy command and i was losing my data.